# Web aplication Deploy from Visual Studio not succeeding

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webdeploy

I'm trying to publish my ASP.NET web application from Visual Studio 2013 to a server with IIS on which I've installed Web Deploy 3.6.

When I try to publish thru the wizard when clicking the Validate Connection Button I get the following error

> Could not connect to the remote computer ("") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC. The remote server returned an error (550)

I looked at the link given and a number of other articles on Configuring WebDeploy and troubleshooting problems with WebDeploy and everything seems to be configured and running properly.

I checked the W3SVC1 log on the server and the attempts are listed.

The first entry gives the IP of the computer requesting with error code `401 2 5 0` or `401 2 5 3234` yesterday.

The rest of the entries doen't show that IP but show the User Name for the server being used and gives error `550 0 0 15` or `550 0 0 0` or `550 0 0 343` or `550 0 0 31`.

I have a site running on that IIS and I can connect to it from the same machine Visual Studio is on.

Could there be a problem connecting to WebDeploy 3.6 from Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Originally I wrote in the Publish Web Wizard in the Connection details for Site Name:  `Server IPAddress/MySiteName` and in the Destination URL:`http://IPAddress/MySiteName`.

I changed and entered for Site Name: `Default Web Site/MySiteName` and left the Destination URL the same and it now works.

The direction for this I got [HERE](https://www.benday.com/2013/07/12/fix-error_could_not_connect_to_remotesvc-error-using-visual-studio-2012-web-deploy/).